# Compare two rows from same table

Tags: sql

I want to compare values of two rows in one table,
 The table is like follows.
I want to find record where -F sku greater than normal one

```
SKU         ASIN        Price    
CT0144      B013VNZNYU  20.99
CT0144-F    B013VNZNYU  17.64
```

Comment: inner join the table with different alias and the magic is done

Comment: MySql? PlSql? which database are you using?

Comment: i know but i want two compare two sku onw is normal and another is normal +'-F

Comment: Are ASIN values same for  normal and -F?

Comment: Why dont you  move -F to a new column? Like a flag!

Comment: Its a excel file from cilent

Comment: Who the hell is asking questions from my account in Mitej Technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    SKU VARCHAR(50)
    ,ASIN VARCHAR(50)
    ,Price FLOAT
    )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES (
    'CT0144'
    ,'B013VNZNYU'
    ,'20.99'
    )
    ,(
    'CT0144-F'
    ,'B013VNZNYU'
    ,'17.64'
    )
    ,(
    'CT0144'
    ,'B013VNZNU'
    ,'10.99'
    )
    ,(
    'CT0144-F'
    ,'B013VNZNU'
    ,'18.64'
    )

SELECT *
FROM @table

SELECT A.ASIN
    ,A.FPrice
    ,B.Normal
FROM (
    SELECT ASIN
        ,MAX(PRICE) AS FPrice
    FROM @table t1
    WHERE SKU LIKE '%F'
    GROUP BY ASIN
    ) A
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ASIN
        ,MAX(PRICE) AS Normal
    FROM @table t1
    WHERE SKU NOT LIKE '%F'
    GROUP BY ASIN
    ) B ON A.ASIN = B.ASIN
WHERE A.FPrice > B.Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.SKU,t1.ASIN,t1.Price from table as t1 inner join
(
select ASIN, max(price) as price from table group by ASIN
) as t2 
on t1.ASIN=t2.ASIN and t1.price=t2.price 
where t1.SKU like '%-F'
```